# Invoice PDF, add new line in insertDocumentNumber

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I have added the Invoice Creation Date to the invoice PDF, modifying the the `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Order\Pdf\Ivoice.php` like so:

```
$this->insertDocumentNumber(
    $page,
    Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') 
    . $invoice->getIncrementId()
    . " - "
    . Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice Date') 
    . " "
    . Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($invoice->getCreatedAt(), 'medium', false)
);
```

But instead of the string `" - "` I wish to insert a new line, I've already tried `"\n"` and `"<br>"`

Comment: please refereed link it give best solution:- http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/